# How to search for a date and check if it exists in a datetime array in c#

Tags: c#

I have a `DateTime` array, into which I want to insert certain dates. But beforehand I want to check, if the date already exists in the array. I am not able to use `Contains` or `Exists` in my code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < TableFinal.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DateTime[] existingDates;

    if (dsCSV.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        var previousRatingDate = TableFinal.Rows[i]["RatingDate"];
        if (existingDates.Contains(previousRatingDate))
        {
           //if not then insert previousRatingDate into array
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so loop through the array and check whether each entry matches the date you're looking for. Break the loop if you find it. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why aren't you able to use `Contains` or `Exists`? Is this homework? Please show what you have tried

Comment: i don't want to use a loop, i'm already inside an iteration, i tried applying if condition to my code and used array.Contains and array.Exists, but non of them worked for the datetime array.

Comment: you can use `IndexOf` property of an `Array` like `Array.IndexOf(anyArray, value)`. if Index is greater than -1 then it results that it contains the said value i.e. Date in your case.

Comment: Then please show the condition with the `Contains` and `Exists` because they are the proper way of doing so

Comment: @S.J.Lee: your argument on why not to use `Exists` or `Contains` seems invalid. Please how us your effort.

Comment: You **can** use `Contains` for this. You just need to make sure the date you pass to it is _exactly_ what you expect to find in the array. For example, you might be checking for something like `01/01/2018` but in the array, you have `01/01/2018 10:02:00`, that _obviously_ will return false.

Comment: Here's a [quick example](http://rextester.com/OCHSE15343) for you.

Comment: Now that you posted your code, it seems like you never initialized the DateTime array `existingDates` or added anything to it! As is, it will return false **every single time**.

Comment: Is this your real code? `existingDates` is never initialized

Comment: @GiladGreen it says DateTime[] doesn't contain a definition for Contains

Comment: @S.J.Lee - See answer below

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed yes the date i am passing is in the format 01/01/2018 and i am checking it in a array of type datetime. but it is not returning false. it throws an error that array doesn't contain definition for Contains. It happened again when i tried the example to provided.

Comment: @S.J.Lee You just need to add `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file. _Unless you're using a .NET version older than .NET 3.5_.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed i was already using that. the wrong parsing of the value was what was creating problem, thats why i couldn't use Contains. thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `Extension Method` like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
public static class Extensions 
{
    public static void Add<T>(this T[] _self, T item)
    {
        if(Array.IndexOf(_self, item)== -1)
        {
            Array.Resize(ref _self, _self.Length + 1);
            _self[_self.Length - 1] = item;
        }
    }
}
```

now you can use like :

```
DateTime[] existingDates= new DateTime[] { };
existingDates.Add<DateTime>(DateTime.Now);
```

**Or You can use `List` Instead `Array`like this:**

```
var existingDates = new List<string>();
var previousRatingDate = TableFinal.Rows[i]["RatingDate"].ToString();

if (!existingDates.Any(item => item == previousRatingDate))
{
    existingDates.Add(previousRatingDate);
}
```

I hope it help you.

Comment: thank you. i tried this but it gives an error at
if (!datesList.Any(item => item == dateValue))
operator "==" cannot be applied to operands of type 'datetime' and  'object'

Comment: @S.J.Lee you must parse your dateValue to `DateTime` . like `(DateTime)dateValue`

Comment: i get this exception on this line
var dateValue = (DateTime)TableFinal.Rows[i]["RatingDate"];
Exception : "Specified cast is not valid"

Comment: @S.J.Lee What is `Type` of `RatingDate` in DataTable?

Comment: @S.J.Lee Try like this: `DateTime.ParseExact(TableFinal.Rows[i]["RatingDate"].ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff",
                                       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: It was initialized as datetime but converted to string while inserting to the datatable. so i guess i got the clue from your comment and updated my code to var existingDates = new List<string>(); 
var previousRatingDate = TableFinal.Rows[i]["RatingDate"].ToString();

and it works now. thanks a lot. :)